# Angular Material for multi-page website

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have old multi-page Rails website (more than 30 pages) and I'm going to implement [Material design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) with some JavaScript effects for it. After investigations I found that [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) provides the most appropriate solution for me. But I'm not sure if it's good to use it, because I have multi-page site. As I understand basically Angular is used for single-page applications.

In fact I'll use only Angular Messages, Material, Animation and View features. Please advise if using such massive JS framework worth it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does not need to be used only for SPAs.  Here's a more in depth discussion of the topic [Is AngularJS just for single-page applications (SPAs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231251/is-angularjs-just-for-single-page-applications-spas).  That said, if all your using is messages, material and animation, those should be the only components you need to add to the project and so you shouldn't be bringing in anything more than is required, such as angular routing.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I have 30-40 pages, so I'll have 30-40 angular apps, do you think it's okay?