# How popular sites are using angular, e.g. The Guardian, when most of the links I click load the whole page?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm new to Angular, and I researched for popular sites that use angular(or react), I found several like The Guardian, New York Times, Netflix... but each of these sites have most the links load a new page, The rest are tabs or popups. How is that? Where is angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is often thought of as a framework for Single Page Applications (SPAs), but this is not a rule.  AngularJS can be used to build Multi Page Applications (MPAs) simply by having each page be its own module with its own fully formed HTML.

See: [Is AngularJS just for single-page applications (SPAs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231251/is-angularjs-just-for-single-page-applications-spas)