# Using AngularJS for Multiple Page Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, mean-stack, vs-web-site-project

I'm designing a website in which there will be multiple pages. At the moment, I'm planning to use to MEAN stack (since I have some good amount of experience with JS) for the development but not sure whether it would be ideal to use Angular to solve my problem since my website will involve multiple pages whereas Angular is considered ideal for Single Page Applications (SPAs). If Angular is not a viable option for this purpose, then please suggest other alternatives.

Also, it would be really great if someone could shed some light on the pros and cons of using MEAN stack for web development purposes like what sort of problems I can face etc. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very opinionated question. Answer here for Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231251/is-angularjs-just-for-single-page-applications-spas. For the pros and cons of a MEAN stack, you could Google that. There are plenty of opinions on blogs everywhere, but it's really an opinionated question.

Comment: I would say that MEAN apps with Angular/AngularJS are good for [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) applications. Since the role of forms in client-side AngularJS applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server.